# Determine If a String Is Present in a List or Map?

Tags: freemarker

How do I determine if a list or map contains a specific string? For example (pseudo code):

```
<#if listofItems.contains("random-string") >
   the map contains a key called random-string
</#if>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lists

If it's a list:

```
<#if listOfItems?seq_contains("random-string")>
  ...
</#if>
```

### Maps

If it's a map:

```
<#if someMap["random-string"]??>
  ...
</#if>
```

If it's a map and the key contains no special characters:

```
<#if someMap.randomString??>
  ...
</#if>
```

If it's a map and you are looking for the value of a key-value pair:

```
<#if someMap?values?seq_contains("random-string")>
  ...
</#if>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something of this sort should work

```
<#if listofItems['random-string']?? >
   you are inside if block
</#if>
```